# Matplotlib Errorbar with Distance Between Dates as xerr argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

See the chart below. I would like to add horizontal error bars extending +/- 20 days around the first vertical line and extending +/-30 days for the second vertical line, however, I've been unable to figure out how to do this. The code would look something like below, however, I'm not sure what to specify for the xerr term.

```
ax.errorbar(x_loc, y_loc, xerr = [2, 3])
```

[image]
Here is the code that made the graph

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mp
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

np.random.seed(10)
dates = pd.date_range("1/1/2001", "1/5/2004")
y = np.random.randn(len(dates)).cumsum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, y)

x_loc = pd.to_datetime(["6/5/2001", "7/1/2003"])
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
ax.vlines(x_loc, ymin, ymax, lw = 2, linestyle = "--")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it. Used pandas offsetting function pandas.tseries.offsets import Day.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mp
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day
np.random.seed(10)
dates = pd.date_range("1/1/2001", "1/5/2004")
y = np.random.randn(len(dates)).cumsum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, y)

x_loc = pd.to_datetime(["6/5/2001", "7/1/2003"])
ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
ax.vlines(x_loc, ymin, ymax, lw = 2, linestyle = "--")
for x, y, z in zip(x_loc, [10,15], np.array([Day(20),Day(30)])):
    ax.errorbar(x, y, xerr = z)
```

[image]